# Meteor's template.rendered called before the page is actually rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to add autocomplete to an `input` tag when my page gets rendered.

```
Template.friends.rendered = function () {
    var users = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
    // this gets all usernames from the local minimongo
    var names = users.map(function (user) {
        return user.username;
    });
    console.dir($("#addFriendSearch"));
    $("#addFriendSearch").autocomplete({source: names});
    alert();
};
```

The `console.dir` shows me that it couldn't find the `#addFriendSearch` element. To see when the rendered function gets called, I put the alert at the end of the function. The alert shows **before** my form gets rendered.

I have found an alternative solution to this, which works perfectly, but I'm not content with it since `rendered` should just work.

My alternative solution is to rename the `Template.friends.rendered` to `Template.friends.methods` and call it as a UI helper in the template like this:

```
<template name="friends">
    ...
    {{methods}} <!-- last in the template -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be if #addFriendSearch is wrapped by helpers (i.e. {{#if}} or similar) - this way you should wait for the first computation on Template.friends is done. Try this:

```
Template.friends.rendered = function () {
    Meteor.defer(function () {
        $("#addFriendSearch").autocomplete({source: names});
    });
};
```

Comment: Nope, adding a defer doesn't work. I had already tried that before.

Comment: Could you post full Template html?